converting function names to strings inside purrr::map
I'd like to convert a function into a string - further I'd like to use purrr::map() to turn many functions into strings. The motivating problem is to apply many functions to a data frame, and return a new data frame where the column names depend on the function that was applied.
My function_to_string() function works fine on its own, but when I try to use it inside purrr::map(), I obtain the error Can't convert to a symbol..
function_to_string <- function(fun) {
  rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(fun))
}

function_to_string(mean)
#> [1] "mean"
function_to_string(sd)
#> [1] "sd"

# I can't map over functions with function_to_string()
purrr::map(c(mean, sd), function_to_string)
#> Error in `purrr::map()`:
#> ℹ In index: 1.
#> Caused by error in `rlang::ensym()`:
#> ! Can't convert to a symbol.

# but mapping over functions is possible
purrr::map(c(mean, sd), \(fn) fn(1:10))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 5.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3.02765

Created on 2024-06-03 with reprex v2.1.0

You're not going to be able to do that with purrr::map, that function changes the call signature. If you need to keep names of objects, then you are better off storing those as names on the list itself. And then you can use imap to get the names from a list: purrr::imap(tibble::lst(mean, sd), \(fn, name) name). Once you evaluate c(mean, sd), those function names are no longer present, you get a collection of the functions themselves, not their names.

It might be easier to iterate over the strings and use something like get() to retrieve the proper function: library(purrr); map(set_names(c("mean", "sd")), \(x) get(x)(1:10)).

Or match.fun instead of get.
